# how to find phonenumber array of list

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

we have list of phone numbers if any user try to register in application which is one of the number in above list display that number in particular page

```
module.exports.chekingIosPhoneNumber = (params, {phoneNumber}) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var phoneNumbers = ["4243915420","7143367760","5105931884","8472844981"]
       User.find({ phoneNumber: { $in: phoneNumbers }},{"phoneNumber":1}).exec((err, res) => {
       console.log("res is: "+ JSON.stringify(res));
       if(!res)
           reject("The phone number is not registered yet.");
       else {
           res.message = "Phone number is registered.";
           err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
       }
     });
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the question/problem here?

Comment: check the post man collection to display the register phone numbers but to check the wrong number not display the "the phone number is not registered"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what I thought is really your question.

You could write a function to see if the phone number is already in the array, the function will return boolean value.

```
var isContained = function(phone) {
 for (let i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
   if (phoneNumbers[i] === phone) {
     console.log(phoneNumbers[i] + " is registered");
     return true;
   } else return false;
 }
};
```